# How to get cy.wrap() property value into a type field in Cypress test

Tags: javascript, cypress

In the below Cypress test, how to get the '*number*' property value from the cy.wrap({ number: getNumber }) and pass into the .type('BMW2_'**+y**). I have tried below, but it coming as [object][object]. I have assigned the cy.wrap() to a variable 'y', but doesn't work.  Any advises would be much appreciated.

```
describe('Check the submission of a Subscribe form', function() {
  it.only('Verify the submission of Subscribe form', function() {
    const getNumber = (() => {
      var count = 0;
      return () => ++count;
      })();
     var y = cy.wrap({ number: getNumber }).its('number')     
     cy.visit("testUrl")
     cy.get('input[name="dV7Ig2Oe1U-CwgjWGV5PlQ"]').type('BMW2_'+y)

    })
 })
```

Comment: Console log it - y is a 'chainer'. If you `....its('number').then(y => ...)` you get your property value (incrementing each access).

Comment: Or why not `...type('BMW2_' + getNumber)`?

Comment: Fantastic ! Richard Matsen, that first option worked. `cy.wrap({ number: getNumber }).invoke('number')
           .then(number => {
         const someNum = number;
        cy.log(someNum);
          cy.visit("testUrl")
         cy.get('input[name="email"]').type('BMW2_'+someNum)
     })`

Comment: Now its getting the value of 'someNum' inside  type()